# ¿Cómo obtener número de teléfono de una tabla y enviar mensaje?

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla con datos que trae de la base en *PHP*.

Necesito poner al lado de la columna, en donde me muestra el teléfono, un boton que agarre ese número, haga un *fetch* y mande un mensaje al teléfono.

¿Se puede hacer? probé cosas que se me ocurren, pero nada.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                                            
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>NOMBRE</th>
<th>APELLIDO</th>
<th>E-MAIL</th>
<th>TELÉFONO</th>
<th>GÉNERO</th>
<th>DIRECCIÓN</th>
<th>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</th>
                                                    
</tr>
</thead>

<?php 
                                        
                                        
foreach ($link->query('SELECT * FROM users '.$filter) as $row){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['lastname'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['fecha_de_nacimiento'] ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?

Comment: Trate de pasarle el fetch al boton

Comment: Pero nosé como agarrar a cada teléfono puntual y al apretar el botón que se conecte con el fetch y mandé un mensaje

Comment: Podrías generar un botón por cada fila con <td><input type="button" id="send_<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>" value="Enviar" /> y luego con javascript ejecutar una función que recupere el id haga un split _ y tome el teléfono para enviarle el mensaje.

Comment: Voy a probar eso Omar muchas gracias!